Switching Accounts in SharePoint Online Admin Center My Sites Cleanup does not Remove Old Accounts
When you switch accounts in the SharePoint Online Admin Center, User Profiles, My Sites Cleanup, do the old accounts remain as secondary owner / secondary admin?
Background information:
Some years ago, I set up SharePoint Online for a GCC tenant and entered my account as Secondary Owner and Secondary Admin under My Sites, here:
SharePoint Admin Center > More features > User profiles > Setup My Sites > My Site Cleanup: Secondary Owner and Secondary Admin
(Link: https://tenantnamehere-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Online/PersonalSites.aspx?PersonalSitesOverridden=1)
Over the years, I was given a new account, and I switched the My Site Cleanup accounts to the new account and then later to a generic SharePoint Admin account.
Recently, some users reported that all three accounts show as having permission when a folder or file is shared from personal OneDrives.
Please confirm -- When you switch My Sites Cleanup accounts, do the old accounts remain? If yes, then I would assume best practice would be to run a PowerShell script to remove the old accounts.
I am looking for verification as I cannot find anything about it in Microsoft's documentation.
Thanks in advance

Related question: I used a script to remove Site Collection Admins that should not be there, but I am unable to remove deactivated accounts. Users do not like seeing the deactivated accounts shown as having permission, so I would like to clean them up, but the script generates an error 'The user does not exist or is not unique.' Any idea how to remove deactivated Site Admin accounts with a script? The only thing I can think of is give myself temporary permission, remove the account, then remove my permission. Thanks in advance.
